# Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in Asp.net core 1.0 is not supported?

Tags: openxml, office-interop, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in an asp.net core 1.0 application, but its not supported in .net core app
when I try to add reference to the dll I get this error

```
    Error   NU1002  The dependency Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 15.0.4797.1003 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

see the below image.

since its not supported is there a way to work with Microsoft office word files in .net core 1 application?

[image]

***note that same problem occur  when using openxml sdk***

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion File Format libraries for reading, writing and manipulating [Word](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio), [Excel](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio), [PDF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) and [PowerPoint](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/presentation) files, will be capable of being used with ASP.NET Core 1.0 from their upcoming release. Please create an thread in their [support system](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents) to get more details about it.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

As a workaround you may consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. Or just any third-party components designed for the server-side use.

Comment: I tried Open XML but still its not supported in .net core app. as I mentioned in question above.
also I tried DocX, same problem. 
I just want my users to upload a word file to my website, then I want to count the words.

Comment: Take a look at Aspose components.

Comment: Aspose not support .Net core either at this stage!

Answer (score 1):

I am using .Net Core 1.1 and found this Open XML SDK library to work.

See: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

You will need to get the latest CI build via nuget from this feed:

https://dotnet.myget.org/F/open-xml-sdk/api/v3/index.json

Comment: Hi Mark, how can I use that CI build in my project?  Could you please share me a link or tutorial?  I couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: You will need to download the library via nuget manager, but not via nuget.org you will need to add a new feed (in the nuget manager) and download from there.